# Excel: merge data by columns not rows while adding properties as needed

Tags: vba, excel

I have data in following format in multiple sheets in one workbook:

```
sheet1
Name    John
Date    2/15/11

sheet2
Name    Maria
Date    12/5/11
Occ.    Student
```

I need Excel to "merge" data from these sheets into following format:

```
Name    John    Maria
Date    2/15/11 12/5/11
Occ.            Student
```

Excel should find all possible properties from all sheets and put them in column1 then from each sheet copy appropriate values in separate columns for every sheet.

Comment: will there be only one name per sheet? If not then can you post a snapshot of any one excel sheet which has multiple data?

Comment: Btw, you could use VBA and an array (or maybe better, a dictionary? but I'm not sure how Issun would handle this) to do such a thing

Comment: Siddharth, among others, writes nice code so I have little doubt you will get a good solution. However, I must query your request. Most databases have a few properties (ten or twenty) and many people (hundreds or thousands) and have the properties across the top with one row per person. I do not remember ever seeing data arranged as you request. Are you sure this is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern in the sheetnames is like your example, you can use a formula approach

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet"&COLUMNS($A:A)&"!A1")
```

The COLUMNS part of the formula increments the number.
As mentioned, you might wanna consider transposing the data so name date and occ are in the columns. If you do so, change to

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet"&ROWS($1:1)&"!A1")
```